# OpenCart. Can't install module

Tags: javascript, opencart

When i trying to install module i geting error msg.[image]

Comment: how do you try to install the module?

Comment: Modules -> Install module -> upload -> module.ocmod.zip

Comment: First of all - it's a bad idea to use OCMod with vQMod. Second - your module seems to be broken or import-module-system has some changes because it's output 'OK' at first line instead of printing json response

Comment: How can i easy upload this module?

Comment: OCMOD-file is just an instruction script. You can view them and apply changes manually